# Find day of week with most hires

Tags: sql, oracle, max, greatest-n-per-group, having

I am trying to find the employee hire_date (day of week) where the most employees were hired. In my test CASE below the answer should be Tuesday.

As you can see I can list all the days but I'm having a problem narrowing down the result to 1 row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I listed my failed attempt. If there is a more efficient way to rewrite the query I would prefer any input.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date) AS
SELECT 1, 'Lisa', 'Saladino', DATE '2001-04-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Abby', 'Abbott', DATE '2001-04-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Beth', 'Cooper', DATE '2001-04-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Carol', 'Orr', DATE '2001-04-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Nancy', 'Turner', DATE '2001-04-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Cheryl', 'Ford', DATE '2001-04-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Leslee', 'Gold', DATE '2001-04-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Jill', 'Coralnick', DATE '2001-04-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'Faith', 'Aaron', DATE '2001-04-17' FROM DUAL;


SELECT TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') DAY, count(*) cnt FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') 

DAY                CNT
TUESDAY      3
FRIDAY       1
SUNDAY       1
SATURDAY     1
WEDNESDAY    2
THURSDAY     1

/* not working */

SELECT  e.*
FROM EMPLOYEES e
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT employee_id, TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') DAY
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY')
    HAVING COUNT(1)=(SELECT MAX(COUNT(1))FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY'))) AS empdays
    ON TO_CHAR(e.HIRE_DATE, 'DAY') = empdays.DAY;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```sql
select DAY, cnt
 from (SELECT TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') DAY
             ,count(*) cnt
         FROM EMPLOYEES
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY'))
        where cnt = (select max(cnt)
                       from (SELECT TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') DAY
                                   ,count(*) cnt
                               FROM EMPLOYEES
                              GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY')))
```

Produces following results

| DAY | CNT |
| --- | --- |
| Tuesday | 3 |

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=48f57d06c69dd1aab87faa75029c8277)

Answer (score 4):

You neither need a *subquery* or nor a *join* to use if the DB's version is `12c+`, but just use the `FETCH` clause following `ORDER BY` in order to sort the counts descendingly such as

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY') AS day, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM employees
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY')
 ORDER BY cnt DESC
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

Comment: could this also be done with the tabk or dense_rank solution? If so, can you provide a solution for academic purposes on my part

Comment: using a dense_rank(applying within a subquery) would be superfluous I think. A `keep (dense_rank` solution might be considered such as `MAX(COUNT(*)) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY 0) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY')) AS cnt` replacing the current `cnt`, but really no needed for such a case @Beefstu

Comment: @Beefstu Actually, `fetch first` uses `row_number/rank` internally (for `only/with ties` respectively), so this solution may be very well adopted to the older versions with subquery and filtering. See operation id number 2 in the projection section of each query plan in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=af71ce90a4aa6a6d3f4ed6a7bd78078f)

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you asked for `dense_rank` example; here it is:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select to_char(hire_date, 'Day') day,
  3            count(*) cnt,
  4            dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rnk
  5     from employees
  6     group by to_char(hire_date, 'Day')
  7    )
  8  select day, cnt
  9  from temp
 10  where rnk = 1;

DAY                                         CNT
------------------------------------ ----------
Tuesday                                       3

SQL>
```